Le mot "ronçaie"
Dans une traduction par Pierre Leyris du poème East Coker de T. S. Eliot, je lis:

Tout le long du chemin, dans un bois noir, dans la ronçaie,

correspondant au vers

But all the way, in a dark wood, in a bramble,

Je connais le mot "roncière", mais je n'ai pu trouver dans aucun dictionnaire le mot "ronçaie". Ce mot est-il un néologisme ou est-il attesté?

Intéressant ... Ça existe certainement, prenant les quelques exemples trouvés sur Google :

La grande broussaille fournit peu d'exemples d'association. À mentionner la ronçaie suivante : [liste de plantes associées à Rubus allegheniensis]
— Québec, 1942


Échantillon G00221075 ... Bryonia cretica subsp. marmorata (Petit) Jauzein ... Station : ronçaie
— Genève, 1990


Milieux naturels terrestres ... Six habitats naturels ont été inventoriés : ... une ronçaie
— Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, 2022


Habitat ... Talus de voie ferrée, maigre (Mesobromion) + buissons et ronçaie (broyés récemment)
— Genève, 2015


[Zone indiquée sur une carte de végétation] Ronçaie
— Châble-Perron, 1996


[Zone de végétation] 1.1.8. La ronçaie du canal-drain ... Cette ronçaie (Rubus fruticosus) gaine entièrement le canal-drain et sert notamment d'habitat à toute une population de Ragondins !
— Les Arcs, 2019

On peut peut-être y discerner du jargon technique de l'écologie ? Je te conviens que c'est un peu étrange de ne pas pouvoir trouver le terme dans aucun des dictionnaires que j'ai consultés.
En tout cas, le mot semble bien porter le même sens que roncière, la présence même de mûriers étant impliquée dans plusieurs cas ci-dessus.

Plate + -aie is a normal derivational process to form words meaning "patch where [plant] grows or is cultivated" (hêtraie, chênaie, aulnaie, jonchaie, etc) even though it's in competition with -eraie. This makes ronçaie the kind of words you'd expect to see sporadically reappear even if other forms preexist for the same meaning. I'm not sure if it's more common for woodworking professional because it's exactly the kind of person you'd expect to be most familiar with a preexisting synonym

@Eauquidort Thanks, that's helpful.

On trouve ce mot déjà en 1976 dans un poème de Henri Droguet, ce qui signifie qu'il doit être attesté au moins comme ayant fait sa première apparition dans le  français en 1976 ou bien avant, et que les dictionnaires, en particulier le TLFi, l'ont négligé, vu l'existence du mot « roncier », ou bien qu'il n'ont pas trouvé dans leur corpus.
Il figure avec la même orthographe dans un dictionnaire ancien (DICTIONNAIRE
LANGUEDOCIEN-FRANÇOIS). Il est donc attesté dans le français  et a été utilisé en France depuis très longtemps ; ce n'est pas un néologisme et son origine, très ancienne, remonte à une époque antérieure à au moins  1780 puisque le dictionnaire daterait de 1780 (Le rendu du texte par Google est très erratique : « Tan de grâce mil fept cent quatre- v in gcqua*) ».

La traduction de Pierre Leyris date de 1947.

Il semblerait que ce soit  depuis assez longtemps un terme dans  la langue de gens cultivés.

Dans le dictionnaire Languedocien-Français, le mot ronçaie apparait comme traduction en français du mot occitan rounzas et de ses variantes rounzié et roumëgas. Son origine n'est donc pas languedocienne.

Un roncier n'est pas une ronçaie à 1ère lecture. Une saulaie, une aulnaie, une chênaie,... sont des lieux plantés de saules, aulnes, chênes... Bien que les ronces ne soient pas cultivées, une ronçaie devrait être, par analogie, une surface "dédiée" à la pousse des ronces alors qu'un roncier est, a priori, un envahisseur qu'on n'a pas encore pris la peine d'extirper.
